# How do I use regular expressions to find a character more than 1 time?

Tags: python

```
import re
palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"
buscacaracter=(re.search(caracter,palabra))
print(buscacaracter)
```

So in this code it search until the first "o" is found but it doesn't count the last "o".

Is there a way to find every "o"?

This happens with these methods as well:

```
print(buscacaracter.start())
print(buscacaracter.end())
print(buscacaracter.span())
```

And when I use this method:

```
(re.findall(caracter,palabra))
```

it doesn't return the positions of the "o", just the number of them.

Comment: Use finditer and then the span method. BTW do you want to know all the positions of a single character?

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve. If you want to find the indexes in which 'o' appears (ie `(1, 9)`), then regex is not the correct tool to use (even if it is possible, there are better/easier ways)

Comment: Well regular expressions are supposed to be used for that right?. I mean, search for precise things, then you do something with tthat info, like for example print the possitions of what you found. Btw I don't know how finditer is supposed to be used, i am investigating, but thanks, at least i have another step to take towards the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the index of each `caracter` it is faster, easier to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"
>>> [i for i,c in enumerate(palabra) if c==caracter]
[1, 9]
```

If you want a regex, use [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) which return a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) which contains the index:

```
>>> [m.span()[0] for m in re.finditer(rf'{caracter}', palabra)]
[1, 9]
```

Comment: I dont understand [m.span()[0] for m in re.finditer(rf'{caracter}', palabra)]: not the rf part, neither why are you using m.span()[0] instead of .start, which returns the same. Neither why is before the loop

Comment: @Victotem Except for some edge-cases, `m.span` returns the tuple `(m.start(), m.end())`, hence `m.start()` and `m.span()[0]` are equivalent. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: Use `m.start()` if you wish. *My* muscle memory goes to `m.span` since *usually* you want something more than just a character.